# Linux Mint Dual Boot automatic install, what does it *EXACTLY* do?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, installation, linux-mint

I have 2 "free spaces" in my disk

- (one because i erased "System Reserved"(windows still work ofc), it has about 150 mb)
- 40,000 MB free (which i saved for my linux mint installation).
- In addition I have HP_Recovery and HP_TOOLS partitions.

Will "Install Linux Mint alongside windows 7" option erase those partitions?, will it use all the "free spaces"?

I don't want to mess with manual partitioning unless it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You must have that 40 GB *unallocated*, *not* in a partition. That space can be separated beforehand with the Windows Disk Manager, or done during [installation by the Linux Mint installer](https://itsfoss.com/guide-install-linux-mint-16-dual-boot-windows/), which should ask you where you want to put your new files (and possibly to create an additional swap partition). No other data or partion on your computer should be affected.

**N.B. It still is a *very* good idea to make and verify a complete disk image before the installation, lest something go wrong.** The fastest and easiest way to revert after installation issues (whether from Windows updates, user error or other cause) is with a disk image and rescue media.